# Sniff HTTP packets using NKE

Tags: macos, network-programming, packet-sniffers, kernel-extension

I'm trying to read http requests and responses by making a KEXT using NKE. I registered a socket filter, whenever I'm getting data I'm printing mbuf using a code like this:

```
unsigned char *dataString = mbuf_data(*data);
for (size_t i = 0; i < mbuf_len(*data); i++)
{
    printf("%c", dataString[i]);
}
printf("\n-------------\n");
```

I can read http requests and some responses data from logs but can't see any **HTML** content.
I was wondering if I'm not correctly reading mbuf or is it some other problem?

Comment: in which callback the html and css will be logged? mind to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/52219440/2060605

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mbuf`s are actually linked lists of memory buffers, so if you're only inspecting the head of the list, that could be why you can't see all the data. You want to do something like this:

```
for (mbuf_t mb = *data; mb; mb = mbuf_next(mb))
{
  unsigned char* dataString = mbuf_data(mb);
  size_t len = mbuf_len(mb);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    printf("%c", dataString[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n-------------\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I can see some html tags this way but it's still not the complete html codes, for instance I can't see any <html> or there is not any data for download events. The most important part for me is finding the download events.

Comment: Are you taking the `Content-Encoding` HTTP response header into account? If this is `deflate` or `gzip`, then the body will be compressed, so you'll need to decompress the data stream to inspect it. I don't know what you mean by "download events", please be more specific.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to Content-Encoding thanks for mentioning it. I'm trying to read HTTP requests and responses in order to find out when a browser is about to start a download, pass the download link to another app and prevent the download in browser by manipulating those packets.

Comment: Any HTTP response that has the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; …` is definitely a download. Not all downloads have that header though, so you'll have to maintain a list of `Content-Type:` values (e.g. `application/octet-stream`) that the browser can't open itself. You might run into problems with AJAX requests though. In general, I would advise using a browser extension to do this instead. (it's easier and less error-prone)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Writing a browser extension was the first thing I tried but unfortunately they are so limited. For instance safari extensions cannot be informed about downloads. Catching downloads this way requires another thing as well, I should be able to track a HTTP response back to it's specific HTTP request in order to find download url which I think is possible by storing requests and using Sequence Number in TCP headers to track them.

Comment: For browsers where extensions don't have access at the HTTP level, you can definitely write a browser *plugin* (not *extension*) that takes care of unhandled MIME types. Doing this in the kernel seems overkill to me. And yes, you'd need to do full HTTP connection tracking to match up request URL and any cookies etc. that might need to be sent.