# Monitoring Network Packets Using Network Kernal Extension

Tags: c, memory, buffer, packet-sniffers, kernel-extension

I am building NKE(Network Kernal Extension) for filtering and modifying the packets on the fly. **myipfilter_output_redirect** callback gives **mbuf_t** pointer and based on the researched knowledge it has every information related to the network call.
I want to read the html from this mbuf_t and inject one ***css/html*** into it. how can I achieve it?

```
static errno_t myipfilter_output(void* cookie, mbuf_t* data, ipf_pktopts_t options) {
    if (data)
        log_ip_packet(data, kMyFiltDirOut);
    return 0;
}

static errno_t myipfilter_input(void* cookie, mbuf_t* data, int offset, u_int8_t protocol) {
    if (data)
        log_ip_packet(data, kMyFiltDirIn);
    return 0;
}

static void myipfilter_detach(void* cookie) {
    /* cookie isn't dynamically allocated, no need to free in this case */
    struct myfilter_stats* stats = (struct myfilter_stats*)cookie;
    printf("UDP_IN %lu UDP OUT: %lu TCP_IN: %lu TCP_OUT: %lu ICMP_IN: %lu ICMP OUT: %lu OTHER_IN: %lu OTHER_OUT: %lu\n",
           stats->udp_packets[kMyFiltDirIn],
           stats->udp_packets[kMyFiltDirOut],
           stats->tcp_packets[kMyFiltDirIn],
           stats->tcp_packets[kMyFiltDirOut],
           stats->icmp_packets[kMyFiltDirIn],
           stats->icmp_packets[kMyFiltDirOut],
           stats->other_packets[kMyFiltDirIn],
           stats->other_packets[kMyFiltDirOut]);
    g_filter_detached = TRUE;
}

static struct ipf_filter g_my_ip_filter = {
    &g_filter_stats,
    "com.xxx.NetworKext",
    myipfilter_input,
    myipfilter_output_redirect,  //    myipfilter_output,
    myipfilter_detach
};

kern_return_t MyIPFilter_start () {
    printf("MyIPFilter_start called");
    int result;
    result = ipf_addv4(&g_my_ip_filter, &g_filter_ref);
    return result;
}

kern_return_t MyIPFilter_stop () {
    printf("MyIPFilter_stop called");
    ipf_remove(g_filter_ref);
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}


static errno_t myipfilter_output_redirect(void* cookie, mbuf_t* data, ipf_pktopts_t options)
{
    // not printing all html and css tags
    printf("myipfilter_output_redirect called");
    unsigned char* dataString = NULL;
    for (mbuf_t mb = *data; mb; mb = mbuf_next(mb))
    {
        dataString = mbuf_data(mb);
        size_t len = mbuf_len(mb);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", dataString[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("dataString: %s", dataString);
}
```

I have made a sample repo if you can help here anything.

Comment: An network buffer will likely contain only a portion of any HTML resource being sent to/from your node.  What you are trying to do won't work well.

Comment: Right now I am getting http header but not the html. So where should I look for html? @ewindes

Comment: The HTML will (in general) be split over multiple mbufs that follow the one with the header.  You need a new plan.  Have you considered an HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 0):

you should choose socket filter and in order to retrieve HTML payload you should read mbuf_t using mbuf_t data. Below method prints every bytes from the starts so put it in your `sf_data_in_func` call back.

> print_mbuf_data(*data);

This would work for you.

```
static void print_mbuf_data(mbuf_t mb){
    //    unsigned char *tmp_buffer = (unsigned char *) mbuf_datastart(mb);
        unsigned char *tmp_buffer = (unsigned char *) mbuf_data(mb);
        unsigned long line = 0, index = 0, character = 0, hex_length = 0x80; // hex_length has limit of 64 decimal
        unsigned long length = mbuf_len(mb);
        unsigned char hex_temp [0x80]; // buffer has limit of 64 decimal

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 0x80)
    {
        memset(hex_temp, 0, hex_length);
        line = length - index > 0x80 ? 0x80 : length - index;
        for (character = 0; character < line; character++)
        {
            snprintf(((char *) hex_temp + strlen((char *) hex_temp)),
                     hex_length - strlen((char *) hex_temp), "%c", tmp_buffer[index + character]);
        }
        printf("%s", hex_temp);
    }
}
```